# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a script and trying to replay the script. During the run i'm receiving the following errors.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

I'm receiving this errors from the payment gateway hits.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're experiencing the issue described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed), this is due to applied configuration to make JMeter to act like well-behaved browsers.

If you're totally sure that everything is fine with your server, you can try tweaking some JMeter properties in order to workaround these errors

1. Add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
2. In *hc.parameters* file (lives in JMeter's "bin" folder as well) add the following line:

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```

You need to restart JMeter to pick these properties up.

Also above instructions apply to **HTTPClient4** implementation. It is default for the most recent JMeter versions, but just in case you can explicitly set it for all HTTP Request samplers using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults) configuration element.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, this happens when you use the wrong port. Please check if you are using the right URL (name + port).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sasidhar indicated, you may want to ensure the JVM on the server associated with your port # is up and running. I've seen this when the JVM has been stopped without my knowledge. If none of these work, ensure the target server's httpd.conf file is properly configured and the server is actually up and running.